# PostgreSQL: use the conditions from the where clause in a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I want to write a PostgreSQL function that will return a set of rows. Thus, this function will be used in the FROM part of the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM function();
```

The thing is that I will probably need to apply filters in a where clause:

```
SELECT * from function() WHERE ...;
```

In that case, I guess Postgres starts by computing the result of the function before applying the filters. My question is: is it possible to get and use these filters from inside the function, so that they are applied directly there and not afterwards ? I'd like to avoid passing these conditions to the function as parameters if possible, and just 'take' them from the WHERE part of the query.

Comment: You would have to pass the filtering parameters into the function.

Comment: `I guess Postgres starts by computing the result of the function before applying the filters.` => predicate pushdown

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Huh? what's that in this context?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I thought that PostgreSQL query optimizer supports predicate pushdown so the query from function is merged with outer query to get better performance. Of course not for every case but most modern RDBMSes do it.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Ah, I see. You are talking about function inlining, that is, replacing the function with its definition (that's more "function pull-up" than "parameter push-down"). This can only be done with SQL functions, and only in certain cases. But yes, in that case it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments by Lukasz and Laurenz, what I was looking for was function inlining : https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions